# Split Flat File using Java

Tags: java, split

I am fairly new to java and need some help.  I have flat file with 10 columns and a total of, lets say, 9750 rows.  All the rows are pipe delimited.  I need to split the file into 2000 rows each (5 files).

How do I do this in Java?

Comment: Please edit your post to show us what you've tried so far, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq.  You haven't shown us any attempt to do this yourself.

Comment: What delimits the columns?  Commas or spaces?  Also, does your file not have any carriage returns in it?  So basically, if your file doesn't have any carriage returns in it - it is just one really long line?  i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,9,10|11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20!21,22 ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple enough algorithm:

1. Read a line from your file "file.txt"
2. Write the line to "file1.txt"
3. Repeat for a total of 2000 times
4. Read a line from your file "file.txt"
5. Write the line to "file2.txt"
6. Repeat for a total of 2000 times
7. etc

To read from a file, you can use `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String s = in.readLine(); // read first line from file
```

To write to a file, use `PrintWriter`:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file1.txt")));
out.println("line1");
out.println("line2");
out.close(); // don't forget this after you're done printing to the file!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFPOJO library. The FFPOJO Project is a Flat-File Parser, POJO based, library for Java applications. It's a Object-Oriented approach to work to flat-files, because the libray is based on POJOs and an Object-Flat-Mapping (OFM), using Java Annotations, XML or both. When used together, the XML mapping overrides the annotations.

https://github.com/ffpojo/ffpojo